# Luamacros for autohotkey

Tags: lua, autohotkey

i'm currently using a lua script by taran van hemert,where it save every keypress on text file and autohotkey will detect every keypress based on that text file, and i'm just wondering how i can make shift work on other keys, i mean when i press shift+2 it will display "@" at the text file. does anyone know how to do it?

````
-- note that some of the code has changed since then (it works better now!)
-- Though, I have since abandoned luamacros, in favor of Interception... which i will abandon in favor of QMK.
-- get luamacros HERE: http://www.hidmacros.eu/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=241#p794
-- plug in your 2nd keyboard, load this script into LUAmacros, and press the triangle PLAY button.
-- Then, press any key on that keyboard to assign logical name ('MACROS') to macro keyboard
clear() --clear the console from last run
local keyboardIdentifier = '0000AAA'


--You need to get the identifier code for the keyboard with name "MACROS"
--This appears about halfway through the SystemID item and looks like 1BB382AF or some other alphanumeric combo.
-- It's usually 7 or 8 characters long.
--Once you have this identifier, replace the value of keyboardIdentifier with it

--Don't ask for keyboard assignment help if the user has manually entered a keyboard identifier
if keyboardIdentifier == '0000AAA' then
    lmc_assign_keyboard('MACROS');
else lmc_device_set_name('MACROS', keyboardIdentifier);
end
--This lists connected keyboards
dev = lmc_get_devices()
for key,value in pairs(dev) do
  print(key..':')
  for key2,value2 in pairs(value) do print('  '..key2..' = '..value2) end
end
print('You need to get the identifier code for the keyboard with name "MACROS"')
print('Then replace the first 0000AAA value in the code with it. This will prevent having to manually identify keyboard every time.')
-- Hide window to tray to keep taskbar tidy
lmc.minimizeToTray = true
--lmc_minimize()

--Start Script
sendToAHK = function (key)
      --print('It was assigned string:    ' .. key)
      local file = io.open("C:\\Users\\Jhon Ryven\\Desktop\\2nd keyboard macros\\keypressed.txt", "w") -- writing this string to a text file on disk is probably NOT the best method. Feel free to program something better!
      --If you didn't put your AutoHotKey scripts into C:/AHK, Make sure to substitute the path that leads to your own "keypressed.txt" file, using the double backslashes.
      --print("we are inside the text file")
      file:write(key)
      file:flush() --"flush" means "save." Lol.
      file:close()
      lmc_send_keys('{F24}')  -- This presses F24. Using the F24 key to trigger AutoHotKey is probably NOT the best method. Feel free to program something better!
end

local config = {
    [45]  = "insert",
    [36]  = "home",
    [33]  = "pageup",
    [46]  = "delete",
    [35]  = "end",
    [34]  = "pagedown",
    [27]  = "escape",
    [112] = "F1",
    [113] = "F2",
    [114] = "F3",
    [115] = "F4",
    [116] = "F5",
    [117] = "F6",
    [118] = "F7",
    [119] = "F8",
    [120] = "F9",
    [121] = "F10",
    [122] = "F11",
    [123] = "F12",
    [8]   = "backspace",
    [220] = "backslash",
    [13]  = "enter",
    [16]  = "rShift",
    [17]  = "rCtrl",
    [38]  = "up",
    [37]  = "left",
    [40]  = "down",
    [39]  = "right",
    [32]  = "space",
    [186] = "semicolon",
    [222] = "singlequote",
    [190] = "period",
    [191] = "slash",
    [188] = "comma",
    [219] = "leftbracket",
    [221] = "rightbracket",
    [189] = "minus",
    [187] = "equals",
    [96]  = "num0",
    [97]  = "num1",
    [98]  = "num2",
    [99]  = "num3",
    [100] = "num4",
    [101] = "num5",
    [102] = "num6",
    [103] = "num7",
    [104] = "num8",
    [105] = "num9",

    [106] = "numMult",
    [107] = "numPlus",
    [108] = "numEnter", --sometimes this is different, check your keyboard
    [109] = "numMinus",
    [110] = "numDelete",
    [111] = "numDiv",
    [144] = "numLock", --probably it is best to avoid this key. I keep numlock ON, or it has unexpected effects

    [192] = "Sc029",  --this is the tilde key just before the number row
    [9]   = "tab",
    [20]  = "capslock",
    [18]  = "alt",
    [91]  = "winkey",

    [string.byte('Q')] = "q",
    [string.byte('W')] = "w",
    [string.byte('E')] = "e",
    [string.byte('R')] = "r",
    [string.byte('T')] = "t",
    [string.byte('Y')] = "y",
    [string.byte('U')] = "u",
    [string.byte('I')] = "i",
    [string.byte('O')] = "o",
    [string.byte('P')] = "p",
    [string.byte('A')] = "a",
    [string.byte('S')] = "s",
    [string.byte('D')] = "d",
    [string.byte('F')] = "f",
    [string.byte('G')] = "g",
    [string.byte('H')] = "h",
    [string.byte('J')] = "j",
    [string.byte('K')] = "k",
    [string.byte('L')] = "l",
    [string.byte('Z')] = "z",
    [string.byte('X')] = "x",
    [string.byte('C')] = "c",
    [string.byte('V')] = "v",
    [string.byte('B')] = "b",
    [string.byte('N')] = "n",
    [string.byte('M')] = "m",

    [string.byte('0')] = "0",
    [string.byte('1')] = "1",
    [string.byte('2')] = "2",
    [string.byte('3')] = "3",
    [string.byte('4')] = "4",
    [string.byte('5')] = "5",
    [string.byte('6')] = "6",
    [string.byte('7')] = "7",
    [string.byte('8')] = "8",
    [string.byte('9')] = "9",
    [255+44] = "printscreen",
        [145] = "scrolllock",

}

-- define callback for whole device
lmc_set_handler('MACROS', function(button, direction)
    --Ignoring upstrokes ensures keystrokes are not registered twice, but activates faster than ignoring downstrokes. It also allows press and hold behaviour
        if (direction == 0) then return end -- ignore key upstrokes.
    if type(config[button]) == "string" then
                print(' ')
                print('Your key ID number is:   ' .. button)
                print('It was assigned string:    ' .. config[button])
                sendToAHK(config[button])
    else
                print(' ')
                print('Not yet assigned: ' .. button)
    end
end) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have found online there should be a 4th parameter  `flags` that gives you information about modifier keys.

```
log_handler = function(button, direction, ts, flags)
  print('Callback for device: button ' .. button .. ', direction '..direction..', ts '..ts..', flags '..flags)
end
```

Alternatively you remember if shift is pressed. You handle its downstroke so you know that it is pressed right?

#### Edit:

Modify the code like so, to get access to the flags parameter.

For further information I'd refer you to the Lua users manual. You cannot modify what you do not understand. Sorry.

```
lmc_set_handler('MACROS', function(button, direction, ts, flags)

    print(flags)
    --Ignoring upstrokes ensures keystrokes are not registered twice, but activates faster than ignoring downstrokes. It also allows press and hold behaviour
    if (direction == 0) then return end -- ignore key upstrokes.
    if type(config[button]) == "string" then
                print(' ')
                print('Your key ID number is:   ' .. button)
                print('It was assigned string:    ' .. config[button])
                sendToAHK(config[button])
    else
                print(' ')
                print('Not yet assigned: ' .. button)
    end
end)
```